# Get matching device Token of user and from parse

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, mobile, parse-platform

I created an app using Vuejs, cordova and parse for the back.
I successfully installed parse and my device is registered in the Installation class

What i'm trying to do is to get the device token of the user (in my front code) to get the langage of his device and change dynamically the langage of the app.

i can query the Installation class but how do i match the current device id with the one stored in the Installation class ?

thank you

Comment: You can try to save the user (or other information that you have in the client side) in a field of the installation class and then query for it.

Comment: The probleme is that the user doesn't have to connect to use the app, the connection offers something more but it's not required

Comment: OR is there a way to link user dureing the sign up to the device ?

Comment: Yes. You can add a pointer from your User class to your Installation class and send the installation id in the sign up process.

Comment: i see what you mean, at the end of the sign up after teh creation i can push this information but how do i get the right Id of installation ?

Comment: You don't need to do it after the sign up. You can actually send the installation id together with username and password in your initial sign up request. Then you can get the installation id from the user class by querying the current user over there.

Comment: I understand, but the main problem is still, how do i get the installation Id to use it in  the sign up process.
The sign up is on the client side, do i have to do it on cloud code and get the currentInstallation ?
(btw thx for you help)

Comment: I got it. Now I better understood your problem. I believe there is no need to create the additional pointers. After logged in/signed up, try to retrieve the current installation id from `Parse.Session.current().get('installationId')` and let me know.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear,
But the installation ID is not the same as the installation ID on the device right ? 

what I'm trying to do is just let people have the choice of the hours of the push notification by suscribing to a channel "morning' or a channel "evening" but you can't subscribe from the client.
So by linking ther user to his Device, i could add the device to the channel from the front end

Comment: It should be the same. I am not so sure because of your environment. JS running over Cordova.

Comment: i did some tests and unfortunalety, it's not the same even if a signup right away on the device after installation

Comment: How are you currently saving the installation?

Comment: i've created a ParsePushApplication class  to extend my APP in java and i use saveinbackground onCreate()

`  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();`

Comment: I don't know so much about vue running on Cordova, but can you use the same approach to retrieve the installation id later in your code with `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation()` ? In a native Android application, that's the way to go in order to retrieve it.